# Boolean search and full-text search in MVC 5 - SQL Server Solution?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Boolean search and full-text search in MVC 5 - SQL Server Solution ?

I find solution for searching boolean in DB. But this only in MySQL i can't find in MSSQL

example query:

- senior AND developer NOT leader => return all record has senior and developer word but not has leader word

i using containsable for full search but it not google for all case

Comment: SELECT * FROM Tabe Where Senior = 1 AND Developer <> 'leader' ?

Comment: no senior and developer is string and i using full-text search this

Comment: give your code, where you tried

Comment: i search string with boolean  mode. you can google for this :-?.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table Where Senior <> 'leader'  AND Developer <> 'leader' ?

Comment: no. "leader" and "developer" is word in string in field title, i demo for boolean search string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL query:
Table with 2 columns: Id, Title. I need to find all Seniors and Developers

```
Select * 
from Table 
where (Title like '%Senior %' and Title like %developer %') 
    and (Id not in (Select Id from Table where Title like '%Leader%'))
```

This solutions is not good for performance. You can use the full-text search on SQL Server.
Read here:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx#Using_Boolean_Operators

Or search Engine: Elastic Search, Azure Search Service.

Comment: full-text search has 3 operator AND, OR, AND NOT. not NOT and OR NOT Operator. Boolean search has phase search operator like example "senior development" AND python not java

Comment: @lecuong92 read the link about full-text search in SQL Server. `  CONTAINS` is phase search.